# How to disable persistence with Redis 5.x

Tags: redis

I'm running a 6 nodes cluster in version 5.0.6, using Redis Docker official image and have in my config file the following configuration:

```
SAVE ""
appendonly no
```

I can confirm these settings are loaded running:

```
config get save
1) "save"
2) ""

config get appendonly
1) "appendonly"
2) "no"
```

But Redis still creating a dump.rdb file frequently:

```
info persistence
# Persistence
loading:0
rdb_changes_since_last_save:364575
rdb_bgsave_in_progress:1
rdb_last_save_time:1570058274
rdb_last_bgsave_status:ok
rdb_last_bgsave_time_sec:68
rdb_current_bgsave_time_sec:54
rdb_last_cow_size:445624320
aof_enabled:0
aof_rewrite_in_progress:0
aof_rewrite_scheduled:0
aof_last_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_current_rewrite_time_sec:-1
aof_last_bgrewrite_status:ok
aof_last_write_status:ok
aof_last_cow_size:0
```

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 redis redis Oct  2 19:19 dump.rdb
-rw-r--r-- 1 redis redis Oct  2 18:02 nodes.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 redis redis Oct  2 19:20 temp-260.rdb
```

I have checked if a BGSAVE command are being issued by my application running INFO COMMANDSTATS and that is not the case.

I have tried to set a very big value for SAVE ( CONFIG SET save "99999999999 1215752191" ) to see if it changes the frequency of the snapshots and it didn't affected. Snapshots are being saved at the same frequency (Every few seconds).

Is persistence something that can not be disabled in the cluster? Any other way to disable the persistence?

Thank you,

Comment: Redis will create a dump file in order to sync with a slave. For big databases, the default "client-output-buffer-limit replica" configuration might not be suitable to complete a full sync. When database fails to sync, it will keep retrying, forcing the master to generate new dumps. In this situation, the database dumps are not related to persistence on disk, but to the replication itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration proposed in the question is accurate to disable the persistence.